# Where indices are stored behind Azure Cognitive Search service?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Please check this [tweet chain](https://twitter.com/ManojFuturist/status/1283780956071981058). I am working on a PoC using Azure Cognitive Search Service and I am comparing it with AWS. AWS seems to be [using MongoDB Atlas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0kn-CMLHyg) to store the indices and Search function is basically is on Mongo's default search capability which is built on Apache Lucene. I am trying to find how the inverted indices are stored behind the scenes of Azure Cognitive Search. They are using Apache Lucene which serves as the search engine to search the index.

Comment: Just curious -- How would knowing such low-level implementation details of the service help you?

Comment: 1st reason, I'm curious. 2nd, reason, this PoC, I'm working on, is about a product, which entirely uses various services from Cloud like app services, sql db, blob storage, computer vsion, serverless functions and kubernetes etc.,.  I am a fan of Azure. My team mates wanted to use AWS. I wanted to compare and contrast these services from these 2 Cloud Providers and prove Azure is best to go with. I am using Azure's computer vision OCR based handwriting text extraction and it has best results compared to GCP and AWS. I want talking points on how the index is implemented behind this service.

Comment: I'm happy to shed some light on this for the sake of curiosity. However, I would caution you against trying to use implementation details to win any arguments about which technology is "better". :) Price, performance, reliability, usability, etc. all need to be taken into account. Plus, implementation details change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**

This answer should be considered accurate only as of July 2020, because implementation details do change. This information isn't material to which service is "better" for any particular purpose; just interesting for the sake of curiosity.

Also, do not take my answer to be any kind of API contract or promise of future functionality or performance. We encapsulate the storage details so that you don't have to worry about them, and also so that we have the freedom to change them if needed.

**Answer**

Azure Cognitive Search uses Apache Lucene under the hood, which manages the inverted indexes. As of the time of this writing, those indexes are stored on Azure virtual machine disks, which are backed by [page blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs#about-page-blobs). The exact SKU of disks used depends on pricing tier and other factors; I won't get into the details here (because they do change). Those disks are attached to Azure virtual machines, which for pricing tiers other than Free map to the "search units" you pay for.